# How do I get alerted in Javascript that an image's dimensions are available?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onload, image-loading

I need to be able to wait to start a function until the height and width of an image are available. When this code calls `start()`, it still says the height and width are zero:

```
var img = new Image();

init = function() {
    img.onload = this.start();
    img.src = "sky.jpg";
    }

start = function() {
    alert("Start called.\nwidth:"+img.width+"\nheight"+img.height);
    }

init();
```

How can I make it wait until the dimensions are available before calling `start()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var img = new Image();

var start = function() {
    alert("Start called.\nwidth:"+img.width+"\nheight"+img.height);
}

var init = function() {
    img.onload = start;
    img.src = "sky.jpg";
} 

init();
```

Change `this.start()` to `start`.

I also scoped your functions.